# JSON Python Lists

Tags: python, json

I have got this json file

```
[{"url": ["instrumentos-musicales-126030594.htm", "liquidacion-muebles-y-electrodomesticos-127660457.htm"], "title": ["INSTRUMENTOS MUSICALES", "LIQUIDACION,  MUEBLES Y ELECTRODOMESTICOS"]}] 

mydata = json.load(json_data)
```

And then I'd like to manipulate mydata to append url-title pair to a list paginas

What would be a good solution in Python? I want to be able to have something like

```
paginas[0].url
instrumentos-musicales-126030594.htm
paginas[0].title
"INSTRUMENTOS MUSICALES"
paginas[1].url
"liquidacion-muebles-y-electrodomesticos-127660457.htm"
paginas[1].title
"LIQUIDACION,  MUEBLES Y ELECTRODOMESTICOS"
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.7

Comment: create a new list and add title and url values?

Comment: Yes, a new list with those pair of values per element

Comment: so a list with two sublists which are the values from title and url?

Comment: I was thinking of elements as a class with title and url, json file is very long and those values are correlated

Comment: just add what output you expect

Comment: why not just use indexing to access?

Comment: Well, it's for a later use in another part of the program... but I'll think about an indexing access as well, Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the values to a new list:

```
new_list =[mydata[0]["url"],mydata[0]["title"]]
```

will give you:

```
[['instrumentos-musicales-126030594.htm', 'liquidacion-muebles-y-electrodomesticos-127660457.htm'], ['INSTRUMENTOS MUSICALES', 'LIQUIDACION,  MUEBLES Y ELECTRODOMESTICOS']]
```

To access elements you can using indexing:

```
`mydata[0]["url"][0]` will give you "instrumentos-musicales-126030594.htm"

 mydata[0]["title"][0] will give you "INSTRUMENTOS MUSICALES"  etc..
```

You don't need to do anything to your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
paginas = mydata[0]
paginas["url"].append(new_url)
paginas["title"].append(new_title)
```

You still need to use `json.dump` to save it, of course.

Comment: what does "ofc" stand for?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it means of course. I'm on my phone so the shorter versions sort of come naturally.